# 'cout' is not a member of 'std' (Progect File c++)

Tags: c++

I created a new project in c++ but i keep getting the same error

## Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


#include "Computer.cpp"
#include "Computer.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

## Computer.h

```
#ifndef COMPUTER_H_INCLUDED
#define COMPUTER_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>
class Computer
{
public:
    std::string marca;
    float prezzo;
    bool acceso;

    Computer();

    void Accenditi();
    void Spegniti();
    void ImpostaMarca(std::string m);
    void ImpostaPrezzo(float p);

};

#endif
```

## Computer.cpp

```
#include "Computer.h"

Computer::Computer()
{

}
void Computer::Accenditi()
{
if(!acceso)
{
    acceso = true;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Sono già acceso";
}
}
void Computer::Spegniti()
{
if(acceso)
{
    acceso = false;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Sono già spento";
}
}
void Computer::ImpostaMarca(std::string m)
{
marca = m;
}
void Computer::ImpostaPrezzo(float p)
{
prezzo = p;
}
```

## The Problem

i don't understand what's wrong with Computer.cpp, i keep getting "cout is not a member of std". I tryed to add "using namespace std" and i also tryed to add the library #include but i get a new file called "makefile.win". How can i fix this error ?

Comment: You're not including `<iostream>` in `Computer.cpp` or any of it's headers. `std::cout` is declared in `<iostream>` and this include is needed for it to work.

Comment: Did you try including appropriate headers?

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't include a cpp file.

Comment: Note even though it is all part of one project, each `.cpp` file is compiled individually before they are linked together, so even though you are including `<iostream>` in `Main.cpp`, it will not be seen by `Computer.cpp` when it is it's turn to be compiled. Also you should not include a `.cpp` file within another, as pointed out. Even if this compiled, it would lead to linker errors because you have the same interfaces being implemented multiple times due to this include loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include iostream header in your Computer.cpp file as such:

```
include <iostream>
```

and to make your life easier, you can also add:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

right at the bottom of your include, that way you don't have to keep adding "std::cout" everytime, you can just use "cout"

Also want to add:

You can remove the include computer.cpp from your main.cpp and just leave the header. The C++ linker will automatically link your computer.h and computer.cpp together since .cpp includes the header, and your main includes the computer.h

Answer (score 1):

Add `# include <iostream>` at the files that you use `std::cout` and `std::cin`.